# change a div content again and again without losing previous html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, filter

I am writing a jquery function to filter products by type. It works perfectly fine but when I filter by type more than once. Html Element of product-box named addToWishlist stop working.
otherwise all products are displayed perfectly fine.
Cant figure out where is the problem.
Here is the code

```
//load products data in array         
             var productArray = [];
            $("#product-items .col-4").each (function (){
             productArray.push($(this)) })
            
        $(".filter-btn").click(function(e) {
            var btnId = e.target.id;
            var tempArray = [];
            for(var i = 0;i < productArray.length; i++){
              var type = $(productArray[i]).find('.addToWishlist').data("type");
                if(btnId == "fairness-soaps" && type == "Fairness")
                  tempArray.push(productArray[i])  
                if(btnId == "deep-clean-soaps" && type == "Deep-Clean")
                  tempArray.push(productArray[i])    
                if(btnId == "skin-whitening-soaps" && type == "Skin-Whitening")
                  tempArray.push(productArray[i])       
            }
            $("#product-items").html(tempArray);
    });

<div class="row" id="product-items">
                 <div class="col-4">
                   <a href="#">
                     <div class="product-box">
                       <div class="product-img">
                       <img src="images/product-img13.png" alt="">
                         <a type="button" class="addToWishlist" data-id="13" data-image="images/product-img13.png" data-price="$30"
                          data-name="Aloe Vera Soap" data-quantity="1" data-weight="50g" data-availability="In Stock" data-type="Fairness">
                         <i class="wishlist-icon fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                       </div>
                     <p class="product-name">Aloe Vera Soap</p>
                     <p class="product-price">$30</p>
                   </div>
                 </a>
               </div>
and so on....
```

Comment: I'd *guess* you're having and issue with in-time loading, and how you're using jquery.

Comment: What I can see, you are binding new elements dynamically here **$("#product-items").html(tempArray);**. Try binding it inside the **product-items** section. And call the event after **$("#product-items").html(tempArray);** if you are planning to use it as a button.

Answer (score 1):

You're not reordering the product Elements, you're rewriting them. Even though the HTML of the products is the same, the events you attach to them is lost when you call `$("#product-items").html(tempArray);`. You either need to reapply the events to the "addToWishList" buttons or reorder the elements instead of writing directly to the html.

Here's a contrived example that shows how just because the HTML is the same doesn't mean the event stays:

```html
<div id="container">
    <button id="special-button">Click me</button>
</div>
<script>
    $("#special-button").on("click", function(){
        alert("I've Been clicked!");
    });
    $("#container").html(`<button id="special-button">Click me</button>`);
</script>
```